# What is the best way to filter this specific message as spam?

Tags: spam-prevention

I use my own rules to filter spam emails. I use Alpine email program.
Consider the following header of a recent spam email.
What are the best way to write a filter to mark this email as a junk in such a way that works for similar emails?
(I have removed my personal data from the header).

```
Return-Path: <SciencePG.NewsLetter@caoutchoucfructify.net>
Received: from my_email_server (my_email_server [my_server_ip])
    by my_email_domain (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id t1G104ZA008294
    for <my_email_address>; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 04:30:04 +my_time_zone
Received: from caoutchoucfructify.net (customer.krypt.com [174.139.207.178] (may be forged))
    by my_email_server (8.13.8/8.13.8) with ESMTP id t1G0LElA026251
    for <my_email_address>; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 03:51:15 +my_time_zone
Received: from AT18-731 by caoutchoucfructify.net
    (MDaemon PRO v9.5.1)
    with ESMTP id md50000147684.msg
    for <my_email_address>; Mon, 16 Feb 2015 16:53:12 -0700
Date: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 16:53:09 -0700 (MST)
From: "SciencePG.NewsLetter" <SciencePG.NewsLetter@caoutchoucfructify.net>
To: my_email_address
Message-ID: <6960950.635451424130789265.JavaMail.Administrator@AT18-731>
Subject: Dear My_name , Wanted: Publish Your Paper/Book with
 SciencePG
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-Authenticated-Sender: SciencePG.NewsLetter@caoutchoucfructify.net
X-Spam-Processed: caoutchoucfructify.net, Mon, 16 Feb 2015 16:53:12 -0700
    (not processed: message from valid local sender)
X-Return-Path: SciencePG.NewsLetter@caoutchoucfructify.net
X-Envelope-From: SciencePG.NewsLetter@caoutchoucfructify.net
X-MDaemon-Deliver-To: my_email_address
X-my_email_domain-Spam-Score: sssssssss
X-Spam-Score: 9.08 (sssssssss) BAYES_99,FH_DATE_PAST_20XX,HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,RDNS_NONE
X-Scanned-By: MIMEDefang 2.70 on my_server_ip
```

Answer (score 2):

**X-Spam-Score** above a certain level (usually ~5) should be your trigger.